# how do we add hyperlink to a message box in sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

I have tried the following code but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    alert('<a href="http://www.codeproject.com/">Code Project</a>');
</script>
```

Comment: You can't show hyperlinks within an alert box.

Comment: @george so this means to display a similar looking hyperlink message box , we could instead create a modal dialog and add the hyperlink ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using alert, I would use a Pop Up. And I recommend you to use something like [jQuery Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).